# Using Offset to change data in a given order in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to offset two columns of data to a row at a specific order, but I am not being able to set the offset function properly.

I have something like:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
```

And I am trying to get 1 row, multiple columns, starting in a given `ActiveCell` that I may select (1 10 2 20 3 30 4 40 5 50)

My code so far is:

```
Sub OffsetData1()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = 0
    Do
        lRow = lRow + 1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(lRow, 2)) Then Exit Do
        Cells(lRow, 2).Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `.Offset` won't change the active cell, you will have either to activate the cell after the paste operation, or to use a incremental variable to calculate the offset.

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to achieve ? let's say you select "1" ,which is in row 1 column A, what do you want to do ? copy what to where ?

Comment: @Shai Rado, Sorry I am new to this, I will try to explain better: I have the two columns: A (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5...) and B(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5...) I want to create a row that gets that data and places it as such: a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3,a4,b4,a5,b5... It can be a couple of columns beside the original columns (A and B).

Comment: @DGMS89 to make sure I understand, let's say you select a cell outside your range (outside Range "A1:B5") , let's say Row 7, so you want that row to have A7-1, B7-10, C7-2, D7-20, etc. ? yes ?

Comment: @Shai Rado Exactly that, I want to get that data and put in a row in that order. Where the row is placed does not matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanations are inside the code comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub OffsetData1()

    Dim lRow As Long, Col As Integer
    Dim RowDest As Long, ColDest As Integer

    ' parameters for first cell Paste, these setting are for Cell A7
    RowDest = 7
    ColDest = 1

    For lRow = 1 To 5 ' loop through rows
        For Col = 1 To 2 ' loop through columns
            ' only copy cells with values inside
            If Cells(lRow, Col) <> "" Then
                Cells(RowDest, ColDest) = Cells(lRow, Col)
                ColDest = ColDest + 1
            End If
        Next Col
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @DGMS89 Your'e welcome, please mark as answer. Do you know how ?

Answer (score 0):

you can exploit the "natural" *enumeration* of a range:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iCol As Long

    For Each cell In Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(7, iCol) = cell.Value
    Next    
End Sub
```